# What properties should I look for to find a balance potentiometer for a vintage hi-fi?

Tags: potentiometer

I am looking for a replacement balance (left/right - center) volume potentiometer for a vintage hi-fi. The amp is a Pioneer SA-506. Here is a photo of the pot:

[image]

I cannot find anything online in the UK. All I see are 'linear' pots or pots for guitars. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Go to the site of a good online supplier like digikey, and do a search, specifying "audio taper" in the selection tools.

Comment: A balance pot is an ordinary LINEAR pot. DO NOT use audio taper which is used for a logarithmic volume control. On all amplifiers I have had, I NEVER used the balance control. It was always centered like two identical resistors. Why do you need the balance control? If you cannot find a pot that fits then replace it with two 47k resistors.

Comment: @Audioguru These don't have equal resistance on each side at center position, they'll have 100k from the center pin to one of the end pins, near zero to the other. To bypass it you could jump center to one side and have a 100k from center to the other side, which side is which depends on if it's the left or right channel section of the pot.

Answer (score 16):

The MN on the pot is the taper. This is a dual pot with a special taper for faders / balance controls, not a standard linear or audio taper. They are basically linear, but for each section the taper ends in the middle so at center both channels are full volume, turning it one way or the other reduces one channel's volume while leaving the other one at full volume.

Do a search for **100k MN taper** pots and see if that gets you any results.

[Here is information](https://www.bourns.com/docs/ProAudioDocs/bourns_pdb182_blend-balance_guitar_pots_appnote.pdf) on an MN type control with a graph of the taper.

**Additional information:** I was thinking that the pot in the photo didn't look original, found the schematic and it shows it as 500k so it appears to have been replaced at least once already. You'll probably want to look for a 500k one, although it probably doesn't make a huge difference.
[image: Pioneer SA-506 balance control schematic]

Comment: The photo of the balance pot shows a SINGLE pot not a dual pot. A single linear 100k pot or two 47k resistors will work fine.

Comment: @Audioguru It can't be a single pot, first, it has 6 circuit traces going to it, second, an MN pot is always a dual pot, one pot is M, one is N.

Comment: The schematic has one end of each part of the dual pot grounded so it must be a dual volume control with each part of the pot allowed to be varied like a balance control.

Comment: @Audioguru Yes, each part works like a volume control, but only half the track is resistive. That's what that half resistor-half rectangle symbol means, half is resistive, half is a low resistance contact. It's not LIKE a balance control, it IS a balance control. If you use a linear pot the volume on one channel goes up as the other goes down. With an MN pot as you rotate from left to right the left channel stays at full volume as the right increases until the halfway point where both are full volume, then the right stays full volume while the left decreases.

Answer (score 2):

Google for that part number. It's a (special, see @GodJihyo's answer +1) dual 100kΩ linear taper pot, but you'll also want the shaft and bushing to fit. As well as PCB pins rather than solder tabs. You'll find similar parts.